# Como extrair o título do link de um menu responsivo?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de um menu:

```
<ul id="responsiveAccordion" class="showedmenu"> 
   <li><a title="Página Inicial" href="/">Página Inicial</a></li>
   <li id="category_item_1">
       <div class="responsiveInykator"><span>Teste </span><i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-2" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
         <a href="/">Início</a>
          <ul style="display: block;">
             <li><a title="Categoria 1" href="/categoria-1">Categoria 1</a></li>  
             <li><a title="Categoria 2" href="/categoria-1">Categoria 2</a></li>  
          </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
...
```

No meu código, quando faço console abaixo:

```
console.log($('#responsiveAccordion > li .responsiveInykator').parent().children()[1]);
```

Ele me mostra:

```
<a href="/">Início</a>
```

Gostaria de capturar o texto do link: "Início"

Tentei isso mas deu erro:

```
 console.log($('#responsiveAccordion > li .responsiveInykator')
            .parent()
            .children()[1].text());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estavas a fazer mal:

É `text` e não `text()`

```js
console.log($('#responsiveAccordion > li .responsiveInykator').parent().children()[1].text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="responsiveAccordion" class="showedmenu"> 
   <li><a title="Página Inicial" href="/">Página Inicial</a></li>
   <li id="category_item_1">
       <div class="responsiveInykator"><span>Teste </span><i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-2" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
         <a href="/">Início</a>
          <ul style="display: block;">
             <li><a title="Categoria 1" href="/categoria-1">Categoria 1</a></li>  
             <li><a title="Categoria 2" href="/categoria-1">Categoria 2</a></li>  
          </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Tal como o Sergio disse com razão, aproveito para complementar dizendo que neste caso funciona bem assim (também funcionaria com, `.textContent` ou o `.innerHTML`). Mas existem [casos em que não funcionaria](https://jsfiddle.net/6gfLzcjo/1/) fazendo desta forma

Comment: Ok, erra isso mesmo, obrigado!

Comment: De nada @IvanFerrer

Comment: Miguel (e @IvanFerrer) , vale a pena referir que `.text` [só funciona em alguns elementos](https://jsfiddle.net/6gfLzcjo/1/). É parte da [API do HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#dom-a-text) e seria melhor usar o `.textContent` ou o `.innerHTML`.

Comment: Editado @Sergio. Obgado pela dica

Answer (score 1):

Uma vez que esse `<a>` é *sibling* (elemento seguinte no mesmo nível do DOM) podes usar `.next()` e para usar o texto podess usar `.html()` ou `.text();`

```
var texto = $('#responsiveAccordion > li .responsiveInykator').next().text();
alert(texto);
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wo01rf6x/

Comment: Sergio porque `text()` resulta assim, e não como o Ivan fez?

Comment: @Miguel quando se usa `[1]` fica-se com o elemento do DOM, "raw", que já não é um objeto jQuery. Por isso não dá. Nesse caso `.innerHTML` ou `.textContent` seria o melhor.

Comment: Entendi, obgado

Comment: Para não perder o objeto, resolvi da seguinte maneira: `$('#responsiveAccordion > li .responsiveInykator').parent().children('ul li a:eq(0)').text();`